# Code corrupt, program still works in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to protect a excel with password via excel.

Its working fine, no error shown while running but after completing the macro, the excel i try to open is getting corrupted.

Am i missing something

```
Sub pwdprotect()

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Junior.xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Junior.xlsx", 
FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="abc", 
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Got it..apologies for missing the basic point

Answer (score 0):

You're saving the file as xlNormal which corresponds to the `.xls` file type, so you must use the `.xls` as the extension, not `.xlsx`.

If you want to save as `.xlsx` use `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`